# How to get a user's repositories from Gitlab just like get from Gtihub?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am trying to get a user's repositories through a Gitlab server **URL** and the **username**.after read the [Gitlab API Document](https://git.framasoft.org/help/api/projects.md) , I find that I need a private token first , even if I have a private token , I can only get my own repositories.

So,I tried the github's API , just call the RESTful API `https://api.github.com/users/username/repos`, then I can get all repositories that belong to the user.

If there are any method I can get a user's public repositories from a GitLab server without any private token ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to provide your `PRIVATE-TOKEN` in order to use the API.

Currently there is no API methods that support listing other users projects. However, if the projects are inside a group you can do that with the [Groups API](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#list-a-groups-projects).

Please check the official API documentation located at [doc.gitlab.com/ee/api](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/api/), as this page updates with the latest documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the private token is mandatory, but you can change the Repository owner after clicking "Connect to VCS server". This option is under the 'Repository' Combobox in the next configuration window.

```
Repositories are listed for owner . **Change**
```

Then, providing new "Repository Owner" refreshes the project list in Repository ComboBox and you can pick other repo.

Be sure that "VCS Login" doesn't change. If it does, try to refresh the site. It might be a bug, so refreshing helped in my case. Bacause as long as I was changing the Repository Owner, the VCS login was changing too... It might also produce "Unable to perform operation" error if your projects are inside a group in GitLab(not your name namespace). 
I'm trying to solve this issue in my case, bacause it's happenning this way.